# .htaccess point to default directory specified in text file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, file, mod-rewrite, text

i have a hard tym setting up htaccess to perform following:
on my site i have these files/folders

1. .default.txt - (text file - containing default app version to be used)
2. v1.0 - (folder containing v1.0 app files)
3. v1.2 - (folder containing v1.2 app files)

**TASK:**

The .default.txt file contains just set app version e.g: v1.0

What i want to do as make apache server serve the directory specified in the .default.txt file. i.e example.com/apps/app1 will load example.com/apps/app1/v1.0

So when i want to use v1.2 of the app i just use php script to change .default.txt content from v1.0 to v1.2

Comment: instead of changing .default.txt you can use your php script to create a new .htaccess

Comment: Of you have SSH access, use a symlink instead of a text file.